# Having Trouble with Results in Concatenating Txt Files

Tags: java, concatenation, text-files

I am making a Student Project allocation system reading from txt files. This reads the files and gives them the best project. I previously tried making all the project choices with on a separate line to the information about the student (name, email and ID) and it did work. However I've tried to put them all in the one line and it is skipping ahead when I should see someone who has not selected four projects. Here is what the txt file is:

```
7                                   
Allan,A a.allan@outlook.ac.uk 53027 1 3 4 2
Brown,B b.brown@outlook.ac.uk 45696 1 2 3 4
Craig,C c.craig@outlook.ac.uk 45667 2 1 4 3
Douglas,D d.douglas@outlook.ac.uk 52981 3 4 1 2
Edward,E e.edward@outlook.ac.uk 45048 3
Findlay,F f.findlay@outlook.ac.uk 46904 2 1 3
Graham,G g.graham@outlook.ac.uk 58733 2 4
```

The top number '7' is the amount of students, the long number is the ID and the other numbers are the project numbers. When the Debugger reaches Edward,E's 1st and only choice of project '3' the program thinks that his 2nd choice is Findlay,F and causes a NumberFormatException bug. Here is the code so far:

```
public Student(int id,Scanner scanner) {
        listOfPreferences=new ArrayList<Project>();
        projectID= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        setID(id);

        String name=scanner.next();
        this.setName(name);

        String email=scanner.next();
        this.setEmail(email);

        String ID = scanner.next();
        this.setID(id);

        //scanner.nextLine();
        String preferences=scanner.next();
        String totalPreferences[] = preferences.split(" ");

        String preferences2=scanner.next();
        String totalPreferences2[] = preferences2.split(" ");

        String preferences3=scanner.next();
        String totalPreferences3[] = preferences3.split(" ");

        String preferences4=scanner.next();
        String totalPreferences4[] = preferences4.split(" ");

        for(String project: totalPreferences)
        {
            projectID.add(Integer.valueOf(project));
        }


        for(String project: totalPreferences2)
        {
            projectID.add(Integer.valueOf(project));
        }

        for(String project: totalPreferences3)
        {
            projectID.add(Integer.valueOf(project));
        }

        for(String project: totalPreferences4)
        {
            projectID.add(Integer.valueOf(project));
        }
}
```

Can anyone help as I'm really stuck?

Comment: Please ask if you have questions about the answer posted

Answer (score 0):

Change your approach to create code that handles each line in isolation. Assuming that one line of data can be put into an object of type Student, you'd do something like:

```
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxLineCount; i++) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    students.add(processLine(line));
}
```

```
public Student processLine(String line) {
    // code here to create a data object from each line
    // using either String#split(..)
    // or using a separate Scanner created for each line and then disposed
    return new Student(....); // create your data object from the processed line
}
```

Note that the number of trailing numbers can vary, and so you will need to use a while loop using `while (someScanner.hasNextInt())` to loop through these, *if using a Scanner*

For example:

```
public Student processLine(String line) {
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

    String name = lineScanner.next();
    String email = lineScanner.next();
    String id = lineScanner.next();

    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while(lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        values.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
    }       
    lineScanner.dispose(); // done with the line scanner

    // using data collected above create my data or Student?
    return new Student(...);        
}
```

Separate issue: don't pass the Scanner into your Student constructor, as you should not mix your logical classes, such as Student, and your UI (user interface) code. Instead give Student a constructor that takes data that makes sense -- a name, email, id, .... and collect the data in the UI section of your program, creating Student objects as data is collected.